# Populating a DataGridView with query string

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm having all sorts of problems getting this to work correctly. I think my biggest problem is getting the connection string formatted properly, but I'm not quite sure.
Any help on getting this working?

Here is my code:

```
//Builds strQuery into the query that the user specifies
strQuery = strQuery + selectedWorkouts + " ORDER BY NEWID()";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; AttachDBFileName=C:\\Users\\Eric\\documents\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\Whats the Workout\\Whats the Workout\\WhatsTheWorkout.mdf; Integrated Security = true");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Workouts");
workoutGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables["Workouts"].DefaultView;

con.Close();
```

Comment: What exactly is happening that makes job say it is "not working"? Exception being thrown? No data displayed? Something else? Please provide details and be as specific as possible. This is not the place to be vague. What have you tried to correct it?

Comment: Sorry about that. At the moment I'm getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll". Says I have an unhandled SQLException at con.Open();.

Comment: You have to verify your connection string.  What type of database are you connecting to? Mdf looks like access, but with access mdf was the security files and not the data itself. Can you let us know what type of database

Comment: A good way to get your connection string is to use the settings designer in visual studio and create an application setting for the connection. You pick the database, the credentials and everything and it will verify it. You then can access it in your code using the settings class instead of hard coding the string

Comment: Also, you are vulnerable to SQL injection. Look up how to use parameters in your command object assuming your query string contains any sort of info input by a user.

Comment: The only input from the user would be from selecting checkboxes. I actually created the database within Visual Studio 2013 so I couldn't really tell you what database it is, although I'm guessing Microsoft SQL Server. When I pull the connection string from the properties window in VS I get Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Eric\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Whats the Workout\Whats the Workout\WhatsTheWorkout.mdf";Integrated Security=True. I'm not really sure the best way to format that to make it work.